# How to serialize Java POJOs generated from Avro

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I am trying to write a generic serializer for my Avro-generated Java objects. By begging, borrowing and stealing I came up with the following method:

```
public byte[] serialize(T data) {
    SpecificDatumWriter<T> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(tClass);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
    try {
        writer.write(data, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        ByteBuffer serialized = ByteBuffer.allocate(out.toByteArray().length);
        serialized.put(out.toByteArray());
        return serialized.array();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the schema included in this byte array? If I try to deserialize this byte array with a tClass of a different version, will it be ok? (as long as the schemas are backwards-compatible)
2. If this is how I'm meant to serialize Avro POJOs, what if anything are the following used for in my Avro generated POJO:

   ```
   public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() {
       return SCHEMA$;
   }

   private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter WRITER$ = new org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);

   @Override
   public void writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput out) throws java.io.IOException {
       WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
   }

   private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader READER$ = new org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

   @Override
   public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in) throws java.io.IOException {
       READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
   }
   ```

Am I missing something?